# Deployed contract on Goerli network with hardhat return 0x000 address

Tags: solidity, hardhat

I'm trying to deploy a contract from another contract in solidity. The code is returning a valid address on localhost (with hardhat) but when I tried on Goerli network it return address 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000.

Here is the two contracts:

```
 contract Test {

    function test() external pure returns(uint256) {
        return 10;
    }
}
```

```
contract Factory {

    address private addr;

    constructor() {}

    function DeployContract() public {
        addr = address(new Test());
    }

    function getAddress() external view returns (address) {
        return addr;
    }
}
```

I am running the following script in JS :

```
const FactorySeed = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("Factory");
const FactorySeedInstance = await FactorySeed.deploy();
await FactorySeedInstance.deployed();
        
console.log(`Deployed factory at ${FactorySeedInstance.address}`);

await FactorySeedInstance.DeployContract();
const address = await FactorySeedInstance.getAddress();
console.log("Test address " + address);
```

When running this on localhost node it work and return something like :

Deployed factory at 0xb7278A61aa25c888815aFC32Ad3cC52fF24fE575

Test address 0x9FA5072032B7a7DCc49533401cec1C47bfcf350d

But on Goerli I get

Deployed factory at 0x742970731639e0830B2c7cD579d71018Fe93C683

Test address 0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000

Can someone explain to me what I'm not understanding here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply because the RPC server are not updated with the latest data.

When calling the `getAddress` function to the `0x742970731639e0830B2c7cD579d71018Fe93C683` address now, you can receive the `0xeA7bB92Fc218B930FA143954EE455A888E913162` address as the result. The same result can also be checked at [internal txns](https://goerli.etherscan.io/tx/0xceb14b379ba2a1b3a6c1335169c8abb313e930a4ba89c9ddc5a427f466bdb540#internal).

In the local network, the node are updated instanly. But with an online network, you should [wait](https://docs.ethers.org/v5/api/providers/types/#providers-TransactionResponse) for few blocks before getting data (to let the RPC updates).